# Which packages publishes imu?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! I'm at my last stage of my project now.

I'm using hector_pose_estimation that subscribes to /imu topic. Which package that publishes /imu should I get?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215956/which-packages-publishes-imu?/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, this obviously depends on the IMU that you have.

The respective IMU driver will publish the `/imu` topic then.

Check out the [imu_drivers WIKI page](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_drivers) or any of the IMU specific driver packages [(e.g. the razor IMU)](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-17**:
Thanks for the link!